# for loop went to super long time (20+ Minutes) iteration when the input has large amount of data

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have two functions here:

```
int getHighestVal(int n, vector<double> arr) {
    int highest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[highest])
            highest = i;
    }

    return highest;
}
```

```
vector<int> getRank(int n, vector<double> arr) {
    vector<int> rank(n);
    vector<bool> used(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        used[i] = false;
    int lowestVal = getHighestVal(n, arr);
    cout << "Pass waypoint lowestVal" << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { //LOOP HERE WENT INFINITE ITERATION
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (used[j] == false && arr[lowestVal] > arr[j])
                lowestVal = j;
        }

        rank[lowestVal] = i;
        used[lowestVal] = true;
        lowestVal = getHighestVal(n, arr);
        cout << "\rPass waypoint RANKING Loop2: " << n;
    }
    cout << "Pass waypoint RANKING" << endl;

    return rank;
}
```

I was using it to implement my program, but the for loop in `getRank` will acting fussy (spended nearly 20Mins to finish) when I tried to input a `vector<double>arr` that contains 16200 doubles.

Why? That was too long for 16200 doubles.

Note: With @bruno 's solution, runnning it on Release mode can shorten the time from 1.5 Sec to 0.3 Sec. Huge Improvement.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212601/discussion-on-question-by-travis-su-for-loop-went-to-infinite-iteration-when-the).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because *arr* is unchanged the value return by *getHighestVal* is always the same, so it is needed to call that function only one time, rather to do in the loop *for*

To use const reference makes the code more performant but also more clear because immediately indicates *arr* is unchanged without having to look inside the bodies

So you will save time (like divide by 5) with just little changes :

```
int getHighestVal(int n, const vector<double> & arr) {
    int highest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[highest])
            highest = i;
    }

    return highest;
}

vector<int> getRank(int n, const vector<double> & arr) {
    vector<int> rank(n);
    vector<bool> used(n, false);
    int lowestVal = getHighestVal(n, arr);
    cout << "Pass waypoint lowestVal" << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { //LOOP HERE WENT INFINITE ITERATION
        int lo = lowestVal;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (used[j] == false && arr[lo] > arr[j])
                lo = j;
        }

        rank[lo] = i;
        used[lo] = true;
        //cout << "\rPass waypoint RANKING Loop2: " << n;
    }
    cout << "Pass waypoint RANKING" << endl;

    return rank;
}
```

The parameter *n* has sense only if not all the vector have to be considered (*n* < vector size)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to always create the rank for the entire array, then the first parameter `n` is redundant – you can get the same information from `arr.size()`. Redundancies can be sources of error, so in this case rather drop the parameter:

```
std::vector<size_t> getRank(std::vector<double> const& arr);
```

Two other changes:

- It looks pretty much as if rank won't ever get negative; then an unsigned type is better choice. `size_t` is suitable to hold any number of elements you can pack into a `std::vector`, so it's a fine type. Only if this consumes too much memory, I'd fall back to a smaller type...
- Accepting by const reference avoids copying the vector. You are not going to modify it anyway, so there's no need to create copies. That gets especially relevant for your `getHighestVal`-function, which gets called again and again.

However, there's no need to re-invent the wheel, there's already `std::max_element` that does the same...

```
std::vector<size_t> getRank(std::vector<double> const& arr)
{
    vector<size_t> rank(arr.size());
    vector<bool> used(arr.size(), false);
    // Noticed second argument? It makes the subsequent loop obsolete...
    //for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //    used[i] = false;

    // using std:max_element instead
    auto lowestVal = std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end()) - arr.begin();
    // std::max_element returns an iterator, though – for getting an index,
    // we need to calculate the difference to first element

    std::cout << "Pass waypoint lowestVal" << std::endl;

    // now avoid calling std::max_element again and again!
    auto lowestValConst = lowestVal;

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= arr.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++)
        {
            if (!used[j] && arr[lowestVal] > arr[j])
                lowestVal = j;
        }

        rank[lowestVal] = i;
        used[lowestVal] = true;

        // avoid re-calculation:
        lowestVal = lowestValConst; //getHighestVal(n, arr);

        std::cout << "\rPass waypoint RANKING Loop2: " << arr.size();
    }
    std::cout << "Pass waypoint RANKING" << std::endl;
}
```

This still remains an O(n²) algorithm, though. You can better, though, to O(n*log(n)):

```
std::vector<size_t> getRank(std::vector<double> const& arr)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<double, size_t>> values;
    values.reserve(arr.size()); // avoid re-allocations
    size_t index = 0;
    for(auto d : arr)
        values.emplace_back(d, index++);

    // copying the array into a second one with indices paired: O(n)

    std::sort
    (
        values.begin(), values.end(),
        std::greater<std::pair<double, size_t>>
    );
    // std::pair has already a lexicographical operator<, so we can use that one
    // – but because of lexicographical comparison it is important to use the
    // double value as first element; the index as second element then, as a
    // bonus assures stable sorting...
    // still we want to get descending order, so we need to compare with
    // greater instead of default of less

    // sorting has complexity of O(n*log(n))

    // we need to copy the indices into the ranks:
    std::vector<size_t> rank(arr.size());
    index = 0;
    for(auto& v : values)
        //ranks[v.second] = index++;
        // pre-increment: you seem to need 1-based rank...
        ranks[v.second] = ++index;

    // copying back: O(n)
}
```

Total now is O(n) + O(n*log(n) + O(n), which is O(n*log(n)) in total.

Be aware that above is untested code – if you encounter a bug, please fix it yourself...

Comment: I'll give a try later. Right now on ```const ref``` it took 20 Mins to finish 16200 x 2 doubles. Very ridiculous.

Comment: warning, *getHighestVal* return an index, not a value from the array

Comment: @bruno: Just the same as `std::max_element` does – well, in form of an iterator, though; the index we get via subtracting `arr.begin()` from.

Comment: probably I read wrong and didn't see you subtract arr.begin()

Answer (score 0):

I think for loop should be less than n in `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)`. 
Also, pass the vector with an address in functions instead of a copy.