# Unreal is taking over 30 mins to compile code

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So I have a decent understanding of c++ and have been following a course on udemy to better understand unreal itself. I've had it installed about a week working great but it recently decided to take for ever to compile. Normally it takes like a minute at most and rarely that but now its taking up to a like 30 mins. I deleted and made it remake the binary's same issue. I've tried googling it i can't seem to find anything to help. This is the message output.

```
Total execution time: 1489.19 seconds
Building BullCowGameEditor...
Using Visual Studio 2019 14.25.28612 toolchain (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610) and Windows 10.0.18362.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
[Upgrade]
[Upgrade] Using backward-compatible build settings. The latest version of UE4 sets the following values by default, which may require code changes:
[Upgrade]     bLegacyPublicIncludePaths = false                 => Omits subfolders from public include paths to reduce compiler command line length. (Previously: true).
[Upgrade]     ShadowVariableWarningLevel = WarningLevel.Error   => Treats shadowed variable warnings as errors. (Previously: WarningLevel.Warning).
[Upgrade]     PCHUsage = PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs   => Set in build.cs files to enables IWYU-style PCH model. See https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/BuildTools/UnrealBuildTool/IWYU/index.html. (Previously: PCHUsageMode.UseSharedPCHs).
[Upgrade] Suppress this message by setting 'DefaultBuildSettings = BuildSettingsVersion.V2;' in BullCowGameEditor.Target.cs, and explicitly overriding settings that differ from the new defaults.
[Upgrade]
Building 4 actions with 24 processes...
  [1/4] BullCowCartridge.cpp
     Creating library C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\Desktop\Unreal\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\BullCowGame\UE4Editor-BullCowGame-3564.suppressed.lib and object C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\Desktop\Unreal\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\BullCowGame\UE4Editor-BullCowGame-3564.suppressed.exp
  [2/4] UE4Editor-BullCowGame-3564.lib
     Creating library C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\Desktop\Unreal\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\BullCowGame\UE4Editor-BullCowGame-3564.lib and object C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\Desktop\Unreal\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\BullCowGame\UE4Editor-BullCowGame-3564.exp
  [3/4] UE4Editor-BullCowGame-3564.dll
  [4/4] BullCowGameEditor.target
Total time in Parallel executor: 1488.05 seconds
```

I've restarted VS, UE4, and windows just in case that was the issue. I could reinstall it if the issue won't go away but that would be a pain. I'm on windows 10 and UE4.24.3.

Comment: My project is like one class also

Comment: how much billion of lines do you have to compile ?

Comment: 123 lines plus a header file of 30 lines

Comment: I confirm for that 30 mins is too much :-)) All is on your local disk as it seems the case ? can you look at the date of the generated files to find what part needs that indecent time (may be you can know also looking at the moment the message n/4 are generated) ? To compile that amount of code on my PI4 under raspbian I will need less than 1 sec

Comment: ok this one is interesting. They are all 15-16 mins ago or around when it finished last or yesterday when i last rebuilt binary. Also worth mentioning that when it was building them and i was watching progress it was at 0% until i got board of waiting for it to change. Also  the compiler was working all 30 mins, or at least using my RAM

Comment: when it seems nothing happens, is the compiler process uses CPU or not ?

Comment: A little bit of cpu a lot of memory

Comment: so the process swap on the disk ? can you understand that use of memory ?

Comment: yes its just stupid its taking 30 min. I think ill just uninstall and reinstall and see what happens

Comment: today in an other question an OP was terrified because his program needed 20 mins to finish when to do exactly the same under Linux I needed 5 seconds ...

Comment: can u link me that question

Comment: the reason is completely different, it was pure CPU, visibly the microsoft compiler in debug mode generate very bad code in c++. The link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452988/for-loop-went-to-super-long-time-20-minutes-iteration-when-the-input-has-larg/61454569#61454569

Comment: If there's even a remote chance your PC/VM has been under memory pressure I would try a reboot. Windows seems to be unable to ever fully recover from a condition where memory trashing has occurred, even after the shortage passes.

Comment: I don't think it has but i will reboot again either way just to be safe

Comment: Im verifying the installed version. Probably should have done that before asking but if that doesn't work ill just uninstall and reinstall

Comment: Well its still having issues but I now know its VS thats having the issue because Microsoft c++ compiler is the only one still doing any work

Comment: no idea what I changed but its down to two mins and i can deal with that